# How to include any js (i need crypto JS) library in backgroud script of web-extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, cryptojs, manifest.json

My current setup including:

manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/cryptojs.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
```

But when I actually call the Crypto function like,

code inside background.js:

```
var calculated_hash = CryptoJS.MD5(textValue);
```

The backgroud console error says,

```
CryptoJS is not defined
```

Comment: The manifest is correct so I guess you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: I do have reloaded even restarted the browser (I'm using firefox not chrome)

Comment: In that case the only explanation is that cryptojs.js does not create CryptoJS global.

Comment: How to achieve that (I mean create a global variable).But , I have experimented with some other libraries such as aes-js and some from github but everytime I include one this results in the same error.

Comment: Each library has its own method of using it. Some libraries only work when bundled using webpack or a similar method. Refer to their documentation or inspect the source code of the included library. BTW maybe you can use the builtin `window.crypto.subtle` for AES/SHA.